# Handler doesn't stop, handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) not working in fragment in android (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, handler, runnable

there is one activity inside this I have viewPager with 3 fragments each are same, inside that fragment I have handler, problem is when I enter this activity first time and exit activity then handler stop, but when I enter again and then exit from this activity, handler does not stop. I also call handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) in onDestroy(), and onDestroyView(), please help me out from this.

```
runnable = Runnable {
            .
            .
            .
    handler!!.postDelayed(runnable, 10000)
}

loadImage()
```

Below is my loadImage function

```
fun loadImage() {
   handler!!.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
       .
       .
       .
   handler!!.postDelayed(runnable, 0)
}
```

In onCraeteView of Fragment I call fun loadImage(), it will start the handler, I want to call this fun loadImage() multiple time in current fragment every 10 seconds, but handler!!.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) in fun loadImage() does not work.

I also call Below, but when I destroy fragment handler will still running

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
        handler!!.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
        super.onDestroyView()
    }

override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        handler!!.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
    }

override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        handler!!.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
    }
```

Comment: Use **handler!!.removeCallbacks(runnable);**

Comment: @Piyush I have tried this , but still does not work.